# connect-flash returning req.flash as undefined

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am currently attempting build an app using connect-flash to hold data from one route to another using the session (or at least as I understand it).

The app in question works as expected on local, however once I deploy it, I get an error where the flash object comes back undefined.

I have stripped this down as much as possible. My app.js is as follows.

```
var express = require('express')
  , flash = require('connect-flash')
  , util = require('util');


var app = express();
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({
      key: 'sid',
      cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
  }));

  // Use connect-flash middleware.  This will add a `req.flash()` function to
  // all requests, matching the functionality offered in Express 2.x.

  app.use(flash());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { message: req.flash('info') }); //here I pass the flash object to the view
});

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
  req.flash('info', 'Hi there!')
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/no-flash', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

my only view has the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Express 3.x Example for connect-flash</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<p>
<a href="/scrape">Scrape</a> | 
<a href="/no-flash">No Flash</a>
</p>

<% if (message) { %>
<p><%= message %></p>
<% } %>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code is taken from the example given in the docs of connect-flash

I have a feeling there may be some extra configuration I need to do, any help much appreciated.

EDIT: 
Strangely enough the req.flash seems to persist but its contents doesnt.

req.flash before the redirect console.logged gives:

```
: [Function: _flash]
```

And after the redirect it produces:

```
: [Function: _flash]
```

However the info flash object I set it to has the following behaviour.

Before:

```
[Hi there!]
```

And after:

```
: []
```

Answer (score 0):

My first step to debug this would be to simply console.log(req) in localhost and in production and see if both environments have a flash property attached to the req.